# C# Interop.Word 2013 replacing substring format MULTIPLE TIMES within one line

Tags: c#, office-interop

My current code only bolds the 1st occurrence of the word "color".

```
    public void Foo()
    {
        string text = "color 1, color 2, color 3";

        Paragraph parag = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
        parag.Range.Text = text;

        int index = text.IndexOf("color");
        object oStart = parag.Range.Start + index;
        object oEnd = parag.Range.Start + index + 4;

        Range subRange = doc.Range(ref oStart, ref oEnd);
        subRange.Bold = 1;

        parag.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
    }
```

What shall I change on my code to BOLD ALL OCCURRENCES of the word "color" so that the sentence gets written as

> > **color** 1, **color** 2, **color** 3

Comment: You could use a loop an this overload of [indexof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx)

Comment: You mean passing a substring of the sentence starting from the last "color" occurrence?

Comment: What I mean is that your code identifies the first index of your search string. `IndexOf(string, Int32)` can help you to identify later ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use for loop..

here is code :

```
int i = 0;
int index = text.IndexOf("color", i);
while (index > 0) 
{
    object oStart = parag.Range.Start + index;
    object oEnd = parag.Range.Start + index + 4;

    Range subRange = doc.Range(oStart, oEnd);
    subRange.Bold = 1;

    i = index + 4;
    index = text.IndexOf("color", i);
}
```

try this out.......